# If Statement giving value error

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula

I am trying to compare two data ranges to determine if they are the same or not.

I'm using the following statement and I get a `#Value!` error message:

```
=IF(SUM(ABS(B2:E7-G2:J7))=0,"Same", "Not")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to see if the arithmetic total of the numbers in the two ranges is the same then this standard formula should do.

```
=IF(SUM(B2:E7)-SUM(G2:J7), "Not", "Same")
```

A zero in Excel evaluates to a boolean FALSE. Anything that is not false is TRUE.

This does not determine whether each cell directly corresponds to its 'sister' cell in the other range; only that the sum total of each is equal or not. The values in different cells could be interchanged or by coincidence be offset from one another in a perfect proportion to create an equal sum.

If you require a cell by cell analysis, then a much more complicated formula could be provided.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:E7=G2:J7))=24, "Same", "Not")
```

24 being the total number of cells in each range. While this does not require Ctrl+Shift+Enter, a [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) does produce cyclic calculations.

Comment: Need to switch "Not" and "Same", also suggest to replace the manually calculated cell count `24` with `COUNT(B2:E7)` the formula then becomes: `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:E7=G2:J7))=COUNT(B2:E7),"Same","Not")`

Comment: @EEM - Nice catch on the Not/Same. Thanks! The COUNT/COUNTA won't count blank cells but the SUMPRODUCT will count a blank equal to another blank so unless you adjust the COUNT/COUNTA with COUNTBLANK it will not be accurate. However, if zero-length strings (e.g. `""`) are returned by a formula then both COUNTA and COUNTBLANK will count them but SUMPRODUCT will count only once. That's why I left it as a hard-coded count.

Comment: I see your point, makes sense indeed. I did not included blank cells in my test as I was thinking only numbers but in fact SUMPRODUCT compares everything (i.e. numbers and strings). Actually to generate the number of cells in the range will have to use something like `ROWS(B2:E7) * COLUMNS(B2:E7)` I'll use this only for ranges that will get rows\columns inserted in order to ensure the formula stays valid. Thanks for the explanation\reminder...

Comment: @EEM - I think that something like `ROWS(2:7)*COLUMNS(B:E)` would ultimately be the best universal option. It should adjust for row/column insertion/deletion and keeps the responsibility of math away from the user.

Comment: to avoid the hard coded 24, try `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:E7<>G2:J7))=0, "Same", "Not")`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have strings in your answer or have the formula in row 1 or 8+? If yes that might be the reason as the formula works correctly assuming you

- hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> and
- have only numbers in the ranges

For a general solution try

```
{=IF(AND(B2:E7=G2:J7),"Same","Not")}
```

Do not forget to hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> as otherwise it will only look at the row the formula itself is in!